# Получение динамического value из input в form

Tags: javascript, python, html, node.js

В общем есть python-скрипт для автоматизации определенного действия, однако нужно получить динамический value из input из form на определенной странице. Простым get-запросом тут не обойтись так как значение устанавливается после загрузки страницы. Желания настраивать selenium нет, поэтому хотел написать расширения для chromium и работать с ним, однако понял, что для этого мне нужно учить js и достаточно сильно запарится так как нужно делать достаточно сложные вещи.

Так вот, можно ли с помошью nodejs загрузить страницу и вытащить value, а затем вернуть его python-скрипту? Да даже если просто использовать его в коде на nodejs, все равно будет проще, чем писать расширение для браузера. Или есть какие-то более простые пути? Ах да, взять скрипт, генерирующий значение, и использовать его на python веб сервере или переписать на python не получится так как он достаточно большой и очень хорошо обфусцированный.